# Angular NgRx ComponentStore using signals causes "Writing to signals is not allowed" error

Tags: angular, signals, ngrx, ngrx-component-store

I am converting to using signal inputs and ran into an interesting issue with signals and NgRx ComponentStore.

Component Store:

```
interface State {
  user: any;
  isBusy: boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class UserStore extends ComponentStore<State> {
  private readonly http = inject(HttpClient);
  readonly user = this.selectSignal((state) => state.user);
  readonly isBusy = this.selectSignal((state) => state.isBusy);

  private readonly updateUser = this.updater((state, user: any) => ({
    ...state,
    user,
    isBusy: false,
  }));

  readonly load = this.effect((id$: Observable<number>) =>
    id$.pipe(
      tap(() => this.patchState({ isBusy: true })), // Causes the signal write error
      switchMap((id: number) =>
        this.http
          .get<any>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
          .pipe(
            tapResponse(
              (user) => this.updateUser(user), // Does not cause signal write error because it's after the http call
              () => this.patchState({ isBusy: false })
            )
          )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor() {
    super({
      user: null,
      isBusy: false,
    });
  }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `<div>
  Is Busy: {{ isBusy() }}

  @if(!isBusy()) {
  <pre>{{ user() | json }}</pre>
  }
</div>`,
  styleUrl: './user.component.css',
  providers: [UserStore],
})
export class UserComponent {
  private readonly store = inject(UserStore);
  id = input.required<number>();
  user = this.store.user;
  isBusy = this.store.isBusy;

  constructor() {
    effect(
      () => {
        this.store.load(this.id());

        // Fixes error, but only works the first time the input is set
        // asapScheduler.schedule(() => this.store.load(this.id()));
      },
      {
        //allowSignalWrites: true, // Fixes issue, but is it the right way?
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I want to use an effect on the signal input to trigger loading data, but if I modify anything in state prior to the http call, I get the 'writing to signals' error. This makes sense to me. **I know that is how it's supposed to operate**. However, in a case like this, **is it best to just enable the writing to signals and call it good**? Or should this whole thing be refactored to accomplish this another way?

Also, it's worth noting that I am following the [recommended way of implementing the effects from the documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/effect#tapresponse) fairly closely.

[I have created a StackBlitz to demonstrate this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nh6sof?file=package.json)

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting the signal to an observable before passing it to your `load` function like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `<div>
  Is Busy: {{ isBusy() }}

  @if(!isBusy()) {
  <pre>{{ user() | json }}</pre>
  }
</div>`,
  styleUrl: './user.component.css',
  providers: [UserStore],
})
export class UserComponent {
  id = input.required<number>();
  user = this.store.user;
  isBusy = this.store.isBusy;

  private id$ = toObservable(this.id);
  private readonly store = inject(UserStore);

  constructor() {
    this.store.load(this.id$);
  }
}
```

Without the effect in the components constructor function the error should go away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would prefer that when the `id` changes, then the load is triggered again. That's the beauty of using an `effect`.